# Does Comparator use a Heap internally

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator, comparable

I am trying to understand the order of elements processed by a Comparator, when sorting an array.

Does it keep selecting any two indices at random, and keep the array consistent in sorted order, and keep doing this once it has matched all possible indices pairs, is something I was thinking. Or do the indices depend upon the internal sorting algorithm that `Arrays.sort` uses, these are the things I am contemplating.

Also, does a Comparator use a Heap internally, because to me, it looks like, at a certain point in the output, say, the array looks like this

```
4 3 1 2 5
```

Upon comparison of elements `2,1`, suddenly the array looks as follows, which means it's not just a swapping between the values 2 and 1 which were just compared, but it affected other elements in the array as well. Is this made possible by using a heap?

```
1 3 4 2 5
```

I tried printing out the indices as follows

```
public class HowComparatorsWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HowComparatorsWork obj = new HowComparatorsWork();

        obj.understandHowComparatorsWork();
    }

    public void understandHowComparatorsWork()
    {
        Integer[] a = {4,3,1,2,5};

        Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(Integer a1, Integer a2)
                {
                    print(a);

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println(a1 + "," + a2);
                    return a1 - a2;
                }
            });
        print(a);
    }

    public void print(Integer[] a)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Output is as follows

```
4 3 1 2 5 

3,4
4 3 1 2 5 

1,3
4 3 1 2 5 

2,1
1 3 4 2 5 

2,3
1 3 4 2 5 

2,1
1 2 3 4 5 

5,3
1 2 3 4 5 

5,4
1 2 3 4 5
```

EDIT : I feel, it's not just sorting, but "arrange"ing in any order that can be accomplished using a a Comparator. For example, I could have my compare method to arrange(sort ?) all even numbers before odd numbers. Even in this case, does Java process elements in the
same order as TimSort, since we're using Arrays.sort?

```
public void evenOddComparator()
    {
        Integer[] a = {4,3,1,2,5,6,8,9,7,10};

        Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>()
            {
                final int BEFORE = -1;
                final int EQUAL = 0;
                final int AFTER = 1;

                @Override
                public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                    if (o1 % 2 == 0 && o2 % 2 != 0) {
                        return BEFORE;
                    } else if (o1 % 2 != 0 && o2 % 2 == 0) {
                        return AFTER;
                    } else if (o1 % 2 == 0 && o2 % 2 == 0) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    } else if (o1 % 2 != 0 && o2 % 2 != 0) {
                        return o2.compareTo(o1);
                    }
                    return EQUAL;
                }
            });
        print(a);   
    }
```

Does this mean that, Arrays.sort used along with a custom Comparator may be used for arranging elements in any order, as defined by the compare() method logic, but the order of elements processed will always be the same as TimSort, since we're using Arrays.sort?

Please clarify

Comment: It is not the `Comparator` that handles the order of the Elements. A `Comarator` simply compares 2 elements. You may want to know how the `sort`-method of `Arrays` works?

Comment: The order in which elements are submitted to a `Comparator` during sorting is controlled by the *user* of the `Comparator` (some object that implements a sort algorithm), not by the `Comparator` itself.  Likewise, typical `Comparator` implementations do not use heaps, but there could be a heap involved in the overall sort.  Generally, `Comparator`s do nothing but answer the question of how pairs of objects compare to each other, as many times and for whichever pairs as needed.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` on objects (`Integer` wrappers in your case) uses a variant of *TimSort* called *ComparableTimSort* in Java 8 by default (looks like it used *MergeSort* in previous versions). You can check the source to infer the exact algorithm.

Comment: @Mena, thanks for the lead regarding the TimSort. Please see my edit above. So, irrespective of the Comparator, or compare() method logic, will the order of elements processed always be same as that for TimSort, since we're using Arrays.sort

Comment: @JohnBollinger, please see my edit above. Thanks for clarifying that Heap usage is not mandatory. I understand that Comparator only defines the logic once two elements are compared. However, my question is once again, regarding how two indices are chosen for comparison.

Comment: Two indices are chosen for comparison based on the internals of the algorithm that's doing the sorting. And that can change based on the number of items and the initial order. You can't say, for example, that for a 5-item integer array, the Java sort will always compare items in a particular order. Even if you could guarantee that for a specific Java version, it's likely to change at some time in the future when they discover a better sorting algorithm.

Comment: This question is far enough out of the ordinary that I have to ask if you're just curious, or if you think you need to know the order of comparisons in order to solve some larger problem.

Comment: @PepperBoy, with respect to your updates, a `Comparator` *defines* an ordering of the objects to which it is applicable.  That doesn't have to be the same as any natural or conventional ordering that they may have.  A `Comparator`-based sort will rearrange elements according to the ordering defined by the `Comparator` provided.  The specific comparisons performed may well differ for different `Comparator` implementations, however, because for most sorts, the choice of comparisons to perform is affected by the results of previous comparisons.

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks for staying with me, I won't drag it too long. I am just curious. Thanks for the detail regarding TimSort not being tied to a particular order. But I'm having trouble convincing myself why, arranging even numbers before odd, which has nothing to do with sorting really, should be tied to the logic of TimSort.

Comment: But your comparator isn't tied to the logic of TimSort. As a previous comment said, all comparator does is compare items and return the result of that comparison. The order of operations is fully defined by whatever calls the comparator. If you have logic that calls a comparator so that you can arrange even numbers before odd, then TimSort plays no role. Although you *could* use TimSort and a comparator to perform that task, you don't have to.

Comment: @JimMischel, the part where you said, "If you have logic that calls a comparator so that you can arrange even numbers before odd, then TimSort plays no role" pretty much answers my entire question. I think, in my mind, I am tied to Comparator and Arrays.sort always being used together as a pair, and so was difficult for me to think out of it. Could you please give me a code example on triggering the EvenOddComparator, say that I have above, from a different logic, that is not Arrays.sort. Thanks once again, I feel I've almost understood.